# Compatibility with iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I'm seeing white borders at the top and bottom of the screen when viewing my app on an iPhone X simulator.
How do I get rid of them?

[image: Image 1]

Comment: You need to work with safe areas in the storyboard. The top and bottom anchors of the view with the image need to be 0 to the safe area.

Comment: Set ImageView Top,Bottom constraint to superview instead of SafeLayout to extend it beyond safe area.

Comment: learn about the difference between _safe-area_ and the _left-right-bottom-top_ edges.

Answer (score 1):

When the iPhone X was released Apple released a series of Tech Talks on how to update applications to support the new safe area insets.

1. [Building Apps for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/201)
2. [Designing for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/801)

With this years (2018) release of the iPhone XS, XS Max and XR they added this talk:

- [Building Apps for iPhone XS, iPhone XS Max, and iPhone XR](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/207/)

Watch the videos see how to update the `autolayout` settings of your various views.